# Emmiting Particles in Grid Pattern

Tags: particles

I want to emmit particles in a Grid Pattern as Pins on a CPU. I cannot figure it out. Does anybody know how?

I alr deselected Random Order and set the Density Vertex Group but it still is somewhat random.

[image]

[image]

---

this is how it looks now thanks to MikoCG: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this useful for you?
[image]
[image]

You can use plane, subdivide it to needed number of faces and then use section Source -> Emit from -> Faces

Set Particles/Faces to 1 to emit one particle from each face.

After this try to use different number of particles until you will have your grid filled. Also, you can then apply particle system, remove your plane and place it on your CPU.

This is what I am talking about in comments:
[image]

Because you set particles to thousands, it means that there are multiple objects/particles at one spot.. when you apply your particles, select them all, join them, go to edit mode, select all vertices and press M and select by distance to remove those duplicating particles... Do you understand what I mean? If you wanted grid let's say 20*20 transistors, you don't have 400 of them but thousands of them

Comment: ty this worked, eventho i found emit from vertices to work better (idk why but i needed to set it to a stupidly high ammount when emmiting from faces so it fills out the bottom).

Comment: Yes it takes a lot of them because it still was placing those particles randomly in random faces so it needs to go big.... Also did you check for duplicate transistors? I am not sure if it makes duples, hopefully not

Comment: What do you mean with duped transistors? Pins? They were probably somehow duplicating idk. I tried converting em when they were ar like 20k to check but ut was like 5 seconds per frame then so idk. With vertices i only needed to go like 200 over so that was fine ig. And it even looked better imo

Comment: look at my answer I will edit something at the end

Comment: i am still confused by what u mean with "transistors"  but when using vertices i actually realised i nailed the ammount and dont actually have duplicates. idk what it is when doing faces but i wont check now since it would be time consuming for 20k objects to render merge whatever yk. just not worth it. hope u understand